# Is it possible for a function $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to a<\infty$, but $f'(x)\nrightarrow \infty$?

Tags: calculus

As $f'(x)$ can be oscillate, but $f(x)$ still goes to $\infty$, I think such a function is possible, but I cannot figure out a concrete example.

Comment: Try $1/x+sin(1/x)$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: Let $f$ have a range of the Riemann Sphere. $f(z)=\infty$ satisfies your condition for any $z$.

Answer (score 0):

One example is $f(x)=1/x^{2+\sin x}$ as $x\to0+$, for which subsequences of values of $f'(x)$ as $x\to0+$ exist that approach $-\infty$ as well as $\infty$ and everything in between.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to mind was
$$
g(x)=x+\sin(x)
$$
on $[0,\infty)$, which tends to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, and whose slope varies between $0$ and $2$. We just need to squeeze the domain to $[0,1)$ by composing with the function $\frac{x}{1-x}$:
$$
f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x}+\sin\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)
$$
which gives
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1+\cos\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)}{(1-x)^2}
$$
Note that on $[0,1)$, $f'(x)\ge0$ and $f'(x)=0$ when $x=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{(2k+1)\pi+1}$, for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.